# No painting strokes showing when Texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

I have done texture painting before a few times, so I'm not totally unfamiliar with it. This time it's just not working and I can't figure what I could be missing.

I am using a testing file with a simple plane. 
1. UV mapped the model already.
2. In the Slots tab of Texture Painting switched to Image in Painting mode. Then created newtexture. It seems the recommended size is 2048. 
3. Created its respective Image Texture node and plugged it to the Diffuse node. And left it selected.
4. Opened same texture in an UV/Image Editor window.
5. Go in the Texturepaint mode and stroke on the object.
6. Just in case I saved changes in the UV/Image Editor window.
Yet nothing happens, nothing changes, basically no changes were registered.

Any ideas?

Comment: what type of brush are you using and what settings does it have?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind!
It may have been that having the Fill brush, the cursor won't change into that little circle it shows when you use most other brushes, so it must have confused me. Either way, it's all good now :)