# I can't paint the texture

Tags: texturing

I can't paint the texture.
Although I can't draw, I can fill it all at once with fill icon.
I have no idea what that means.[image]
I do not understand the relationship between the property panel on the right and the paint screen on the left.

Comment: Thank you for your(R-800) advice!
It worked!
It's difficult for me to understand the relations between the  MATERIAL and TEXTURE. But I have to practice every minutes.
Thank you for your corporations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in Texture Paint mode, with the Active Tool tab open (this is the case in your image), look under the *Texture Slot* Section for **Mode**. There are two options. *Material* and *Single Image*. Your pic shows *Material* selected currently. Try *Single Image*.

[image]

Some other links on this topic that might help:

[What does this step do in Texture Paint?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159161/what-does-this-step-do-in-texture-paint)

[No painting strokes showing when Texture painting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/no-painting-strokes-showing-when-texture-painting)